# Dots after chapter and section numbers in scrbook when using chapters in appendix

Tags: appendices, scrbook

When using scrbook and the appendix package I get dots after chapter and section numbers. If the minimal example below is combiled with pdflatex once the first page looks like desired and the .aux file is created.

[image]

If it is combiled a second time with .aux file present it looks like this:

[image]

with additional dots.
The issue does not appear if I comment out the marked line below.

```
\documentclass{scrbook} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\begin{appendices} 
\chapter{Appendix Chapter} % comment out this line to compile without dot after chapter and section numbers
\section{Appendix Section}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is based on a German rule: if Roman numerals or letters appear in the numbering, then a point should appear at the end of the numbering.

If you add an appendix the chapter numbering restarts with letter `A`. If the default KOMA-Script option `numbers=auto` is active, the dot at the end of all numbers (chapter, section, figure etc.) is added in the next run. To avoid this behavior change the value of option `numbers` to `noenddot`:

```
\documentclass[
  numbers=noenddot% <- added; default value is auto
]{scrbook} 
\usepackage{appendix}
\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter}
\section{Section}
\begin{appendices} 
\chapter{Appendix Chapter}
\section{Appendix Section}
\end{appendices}
\end{document}
```